# getting declared field of annotatted class with Annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, processor

I have an annotation processor and I need to get the class associated with an element so I can retrieve its declared fields:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    String className = null;
    String packageName = null;
    String fqClassName = null;
    List<String> fields = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(FieldConstant.class)) {
        if (elem.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
            //              Encrypt encrypt = elem.getAnnotation(Encrypt.class);
            //              String message = "annotation found in " + elem.getSimpleName();
            //              processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.NOTE, message);
            TypeElement classElement = (TypeElement) elem;
            PackageElement packageElement = (PackageElement) classElement.getEnclosingElement();
            className = classElement.getSimpleName().toString();
            for(Field field : classElement.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
               do something...
            }
      .....
```

Obviously, `className.getClass()` returns the `TypeElement.class` but I want to retrieve the annotated class. How can I do that?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. You have a list of classes and try to find which class is annotated with an annotation?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use reflection on code being compiled normally, since the code may have been modified or generated in a previous pass (how would you add them to the classpath???).

However the good news is that you can use the packages in `javax.lang.model` to get the properties of fields.

The following example prints all field definitions to `System.out` (perhaps missing a few keywords such as `transient`):

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    for (Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(FieldConstant.class)) {
        if (elem.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
            // print fields
            for (Element enclosedElement : elem.getEnclosedElements()) {
                if (enclosedElement.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
                    Set<Modifier> modifiers = enclosedElement.getModifiers();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    if (modifiers.contains(Modifier.PRIVATE)) {
                        sb.append("private ");
                    } else if (modifiers.contains(Modifier.PROTECTED)) {
                        sb.append("protected ");
                    } else if (modifiers.contains(Modifier.PUBLIC)) {
                        sb.append("public ");
                    }
                    if (modifiers.contains(Modifier.STATIC))
                        sb.append("static ");
                    if (modifiers.contains(Modifier.FINAL))
                        sb.append("final ");
                    sb.append(enclosedElement.asType()).append(" ").append(enclosedElement.getSimpleName());
                    System.out.println(sb);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```